# Navigation links and Search bar aren't on the same line

Tags: navigationbar, searchbar

Currently my search bar is in the navigation bar but on a different line and I was wondering why it is doing this. I stays the same even when I make the writing smaller and change the padding and margin.
I am doing this in class 
this is my code all help is appreciated

```
<!--

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 29px;
    }

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
    }

#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    }

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color; #fff;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="default.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="rowing.html">Rowing</a></li>
    <li><a href="school.html">School</a></li>
    <li><a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>

<form name="cse" id="searchbox_demo" action="http://www.google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cref" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="" />
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/cse/tools/onthefly?         form=searchbox_demo&lang="></script>

    </ul>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because  is a block level element and, by default, block level elements begin in a new line. That is why in this case, the  containing the search bar goes to a new line - under the navbar. By making it appear as an inline element, the  will stay in the same line with the `<li>` elements that are, as you can see in the style above, also set to be displayed as inline elements.

Put this in your CSS:

```
form{
   display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Because <form> is a block level element and, by default, block level elements begin in a new line. That is why in this case, the <form> containing the search bar goes to a new line - under the navbar. By making it appear as an inline element, the <form> will stay in the same line with the <li> elements that are, as you can see in the style above, also set to be displayed as inline elements.